# Adding motion blur to the object only, not entire image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, convolution, motion-blur

I'm new to image analysis, so please bear with me.

I have an image of a [stationary projectile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwKCu.png). I have the contour of the projectile as an array on the form

```
contour = [[x1 x2 x3,..., xn]
[y1 y2 y3,..., yn]]
```

where (x1,y1), (x2,y2),..., (xn,yn) are the pixel positions of the projectile's contour.

I want to apply a motion blur such that it appears that the projectile is moving horizontally relative to the background. My first idea was to simply apply the kernel

```
 # Create the horizontal kernel. 
        kernel_h = np.zeros((kernel_size, kernel_size))
          
        # Fill the middle column with ones.  
        kernel_h[int((kernel_size - 1)/2), :] = np.ones(kernel_size) 
          
        # Normalize.  
        kernel_h /= kernel_size
```

to the entire image. If I apply the kernel by writing

```
horizonal_blurred_image = cv2.filter2D(src=img, ddepth=-1, kernel=kernel_h)
```

I end up with the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8S7nP.png). While I do get the desired motion blur effect, I notice that my background also changes. This occurs because I'm horizontally averaging over the entire image instead of just at the points lying on the edge (and inside) of the projectile's contour. I guess this means that by doing the above I'm implicitly assuming that it is the camera that is moving, and not the projectile relative to the background.

To attempt to fix the issue, so that the projectile moves relative to the background I have tried to use the cv2.pointPolygonTest function, to determine the pixels lying inside (and on the edge) of the contour. To find these points I can loop through the image and use the `cv2.pointPolygonTest(contour_x_values,contour_y_values,(x,y),False)` command.

My idea was then that If I apply the identity kernel to all the points outside the contour, and the horizontal kernel to the points inside (and on the edge) of the contour I am back in business. I therefore wrote the following function:

```
def Motion_Blur_Kernel(img, kernel_size,x,y, contour):
    #img, is the original unblurred image 
    #kernel_size is the size of the kernel (in pixels). The greater the size, the more the motion.
    #contour = [[x1 x2 x3,..., xn]
    #[y1 y2 y3,..., yn]] is the array of points lying on the contour.  
    
    #Make kernel
    result = cv2.pointPolygonTest(np.column_stack(contour_x_values, contour_y_values), (x,y), False)
    if result == 1 or result == 0:
        # Create the horizontal kernel. 
        kernel_h = np.zeros((kernel_size, kernel_size))
          
        # Fill the middle column with ones.  
        kernel_h[int((kernel_size - 1)/2), :] = np.ones(kernel_size) 
          
        # Normalize.  
        kernel_h /= kernel_size
    else:
        kernel_h = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
        
    kernel_h
```

However, how can I now convolve this kernel with the original image in an efficient manner? I'm asking about efficiency, because I'm planning to do this for 100 images.

Comment: you don't want to convolve the background at all. -- convolve the entire picture, then use a mask(possibly grayscale instead of binary) of your object to compose a new image that contains blurred object and non-blurred background. yes, this may contain artefacts around the edges. a simple hard binary mask may make that more obvious, while alpha blending between both layers will hide it better. you may start with a binary mask of the object, then blur the mask as well. -- there are more details all of this, but I doubt you'll need this looking *perfect*, just good enough.

Comment: “Bear with me” means something like “get naked with me”. I would prefer “beer with me” (ie go down to the pub and share some beers). But you were probably trying to write “bear with me”.

Comment: \**bare* with me